# How to animate window minimize/show animation in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I notice most applications will show a little animation when it minimizes to the taskbar or is opened from the taskbar. However, mine does not, and I'm not sure if that's because I explicitly need to call AnimateWindow or do something else. I am intercepting the WndProc but only to override the behavior for WM_QUIT. Perhaps the code here is doing something to suppress the animation effect, that or every application out there is explicitly calling AnimateWindow?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632669(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to handle WM_QUIT in your window, it is used to exit the message loop. Handle WM_CLOSE to abort closing (Do you want to save? Yes. No. Cancel.) and WM_DESTROY to clean up resources related to the window.

If you are handling WM_PAINT then you also need to handle WM_PRINTCLIENT for the animation to work...